# Session Username found in Visual Studio Debug but not Published Version

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, session

My knowledge of Sessions and the like is small so I am stuck here.

I have a website that is working perfectly in Visual studio. it gets the username of the person logged in to windows (no website login) and queries the database to find the menu items that they can view.

In Visual studio running the website, I can see all menus that I am supposed to and a run of SQL profiler tells me that it is using the correct username.

I then published the website to IIS and tried to use it and no menus show up at all. I run profiler and I find that that it is searching for a blank username.

This suggests to me that for some reason the username is not being retrieved successfully on the published website.

The website seems to fill a a class called SessionControl using the "HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name" function but I cant see why it works in VS but not in the published version.

I am using:

C# ASP.Net
Visual Studio 2010
SQL Server 2008

Code:

```
public class SessionControl
{

// Gets the current session.
public static SessionControl Current
{
    get
    {
        SessionControl session = (SessionControl)HttpContext.Current.Session["__mySession__"];
        if (session == null)
        {
            session = new SessionControl();
            HttpContext.Current.Session["__mySession__"] = session;
        }
        return session;
    }
}

// Declares username session object and properties
public string sesUserName { get; set; }
```

}

Which seems to be filled by:

```
public class BasePageClass : System.Web.UI.Page, IRequiresSessionState
{

/// <summary>
/// Override of base OnLoad sub that initialises session
/// </summary>
/// <param name="e">Eventargs</param>
/// <remarks>Overrides the default OnLooad sub. Checks if session username is 
/// populated. If not formats username and adds to current session.</remarks>
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);

    if (SessionControl.Current.sesUserName == null)
    {
        AuthenticationHelper authenticationHelper = new AuthenticationHelper();
        SessionControl.Current.sesUserName = authenticationHelper.StripDomainFromUser(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);

    }

}
```

}

Every page in the website inherits from this class.

if anyone can give me a clue I would be most grateful as I have no clue at the moment

Thanks

Comment: What are your authentication settings in IIS? I don't think this works if you're running anonymous authentication.

Comment: We have another website that runs the same code to get menu items on the same IIS server which works, but I will have a look to see

Comment: I found that the website I was using was set to run anonymous authentication, I switched it off, restarted the app pools and voila! works as expected! I have upvoted your comment but no one has actually "answered" the question so theres a correct answer vote up for grabs here!

Comment: I've expanded on the comment by @Tobberoth and posted it as an answer.  If Tobberoth posts an answer, I'll gladly remove mine.  Just so the information is out there =)

Comment: @jadarnel27 Last time I reposted my comment as an answer, even after the person who asked the question told me I should, I got several downvotes, so I'm staying clear of that ;) I have upvoted your answer though, it adds extra information as well so that's nice.

Comment: @Tobberoth Well that's lame, sorry you had that bad experience.  I can't imagine why someone would downvote you for that.  Thanks for the upvote =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20610746/session-username-found-in-visual-studio-debug-but-not-published-version#comment30842391_20610746) left by [Tobberoth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/691280/tobberoth), turning off "anonymous authentication" in IIS for this site should resolve your problem.  This is because the following property:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

is typically blank when you allow anonymous authentication.  See [the MSDN article on that property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iidentity.name(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The user name is passed to the common language runtime by the
>   operating system or other authentication provider (such as ASP.NET).
>
> Name is typically set to an empty string ("") for an unauthenticated
>   entity, but can take other values.